# Trying to test the "Example 2.7 Using a data provider that returns an Iterator object" from PHPUnit online documentation but, it is not working

Tags: phpunit

A PHPUnit example from the online documentation is not working for me! Please see below for more details.

Your help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

I'm trying to run the example test below from online documentation but, it is not working for me!

[Example 2.7 Using a data provider that returns an Iterator object](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.6/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit-data-providers-examples-datatest2-php)

The result I'm getting is shown below:

..@VivoBook MINGW64 ~/PHPunit/test-project
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit --testdox dataProviders
PHPUnit 8.5.32 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Warning Test Case (PHPUnit\Framework\WarningTestCase)
⚠ Warning
│
│ The data provider specified for DataTest::testAdd is invalid.
│ Error: Class 'CsvFileIterator' not found
│ ..\PHPunit\test-project\dataProviders\DataProviderTest.php:16
│

Time: 77 ms, Memory: 4.00 MB

WARNINGS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Warnings: 1.

PHP info:

..@VivoBook MINGW64 ~/PHPunit/test-project
$ php -v
PHP 7.2.28 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2020 12:54:18) ( ZTS MSVC15 (Visual C++ 2017) x64 )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies

Comment: If you put attention to the message you can see `Error: Class 'CsvFileIterator' not found`. So, phpunit has a problem loading the CsvFileIterator class. Ensure the class exists and is loaded by phpunit.

Comment: Loading the class 'CsvFileIterator' using require/require_once solved the issue. @VictorAguilar thank you for the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appeared because the class in use was not loaded. Loading the class 'CsvFileIterator' using require/require_once solved the issue.